# Is it possible to write ichat plugins?

Tags: macos, plugins, ichat

Is it possible to write a plugin for ichat to add a new protocol without using the chat framework and making my own application? I want my protocol to show up as an option to setup a new account with in ichat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its a new feature coming out in Lion, just now saw it on the feature list:

From apples site:
Service plug-ins
Service plug-ins from third-party developers let you add new chat services to iChat. Installing a plug-in is simple. Once it’s downloaded, double-click it. Plug-ins run in a separate process to help ensure that they won’t damage your system.

Comment: can't find a documentation about this. someone?

Comment: @choise http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=IMServicePlugIn